# complexity between FCBF & Greedy Forward Selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, greedy

I am reading about Feature Selection methods and comparing FCBF method vs Greedy forward selection method

the complexity of FCBF is O(M N log N) where M is the number of dataset instances and N is the number of dataset features as per "Understanding and Using Rough Set Based Feature Selection Concepts, Techniques and Applications" book Page 45

[image]

and the complexity of Greedy forward selection method is O(m^2 M N log N)
where M is the total number of features, m is the subset feature numbers, and N is the number of datapoints as per "OMEGA: ON-LINE MEMORY-BASED GENERAL PURPOSE SYSTEM CLASSIFIER" book page 122

[image]

although both complexities look the same
yet M & N has different meaning in each one

N is the number of features in the first and M is the number of the feature in the 2nd.

my question is :

if we going to unify symbols will the 2nd complexity be like O(k^2 K M log M)

or they are actually the same variables, i mean N in the 1st is the N in the 2nd and M in the 1st is M in the 2nd and the problem is that I did not understand the equations right?

Comment: All this sounds good, but what is your *question*?

Comment: @desertnaut my question is :

if we going to unify symbols will the 2nd complexity be like O(k^2 K M log M)

or they are actually the same variables, i mean N in the 1st is the N in the 2nd and M in the 1st is M in the 2nd and the problem is that I did not understand the equations right?!

Comment: OK, updating the question was enough, no need to repeat stuff here